# How to get current app relative url for login redirect in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement simple logic so that whatever page a user is on in a site is where the user will get redirected back to after login. To do that it seems I need an easy way to get the relative url of the current request.

I tried using the full url with a link like this in my _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
<a asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Index" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.GetEncodedUrl()">Log in</a>
```

but that results in an error:

```
A URL with an absolute path is considered local if it does not have a host/authority part. URLs using virtual paths ('~/') are also local.
```

Seems like there should be a simple built in method for getting the current relative url. Am I missing something or do I need to implement my own extension method for this? I'm using RC1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you mean Context.Request.Path?

I quickly made a sample project with a HomeController, an Index.cshtml and a Second.cshtml. The Second.cshtml looks like:

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path">Log in</a>
```

And the anchor tag renders to the browser as (tested with Chrome dev tools):

```
<a href="/?returnUrl=%2FHome%2FSecond">Log in</a>
```

You have Request.Query and/or Request.QueryString to concatenate the full URL.

You could make an extension method on the HttpRequest class to for instance return the Path and the QueryString together if you wish.

Comment: that would work in general but I might also need the query string in many cases, would be nice if there was something like .Request.PathAndQuery but I can implement my own solution if there isn't anything built in

Comment: ok, I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct though it is not the answer I was hoping for and does not tell me anything I didn't already know, it is what I suspected. I hope the asp.net team sees this question as feedback, as I think many people will implement a similar extension method for this very common need so it seems like it should be built in

Comment: @JoeAudette a simple method for full url is to use razor to get both:
@{
 string url = Context.Request.Path;
 string qs = Context.Request.QueryString.Value;
}
Then you can just use both in your returnUrl:
asp-route-returnUrl="@url@qs"

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension method for that: `Request.GetDisplayUrl();`
that returns `https://localhost/MyController/MyAction?Param1=blah`.

Or the encoded version `Request.GetEncodedUrl()`

To any of them you must add: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;`

Answer (score 1):

To get both relative path and query string in ASP.NET Core 2.0 or later, you can use an extension method of HttpRequest called `GetEncodedPathAndQuery()`.

[UriHelper.GetEncodedPathAndQuery(HttpRequest) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getencodedpathandquery?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetEncodedPathAndQuery);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-5.0)

To use this method in your Razor view, please add `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` either in your Razor view or in `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

Your `<a>` tag would then be:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" 
   asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery()">Log in</a>
```